# C++ - "Managed" function declaration

Tags: c++, macros, c++17

Intermediate C++ Programmer, using C++17, gcc.

**Premise:**

Right now I am working on a CLI interface for a more advanced program.

To eliminate the need for both code duplication and readability, I want to write a Macro and/or Template where the programmer may quickly specify the parameters of a function call so that a `checkArgs()` function will be automatically called with variables depending on the declaration of the function.

**Example:**

For example:

```
__Command( String funcName, size_t Min, size_t Max, E_StrType Types[])
```

Defines a new command for the Interface, if the entered command matches `funcName`, it will call `funcName` with the required parameters, if the check passes.

- `funcName` = The name of the function
- `Min` = Minimum amount of arguments, 0 for optional.
- `Max` = Maximum amount of Arguments, 0 for none, unless min != 0, then it is unlimited (variable)
- `Types[]`, a list of types, in order from first to last, that the function requires. The last item on this list becomes the one used for every new argument if `Max` is 0.

example call:

```
__Command( testMsg, 1, 2, { E_StrType_String, E_StrType_size_t = 1 } )
```

which will generate a function with this signature:

```
testMsg( String Args )
```

later a:

```
__DefineCommand( testMsg )
{ code body }
```

Will generate a call to `checkArgs( 1, 2, { String, size_t } )` in the definition of the function, in addition to whatever the programmer puts into the implementation of that function.

I already have a way of checking a string "type".

**tl;dr**

I am just looking to see how functions can be programatically generated like that, and optionally, if there is any way to provide compile-time checking to make sure the arguments to the macro are valid.

Comment: Unrelated: Don't use a double underscore. They are reserved.  [What are the rules about using an underscore in a C++ identifier?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier)

Comment: "*CLI interface*" Are you talking about a command-line interface or something else?

Comment: command-line. also wow I did interface twice lol. actually it is a real-time console that displays a log in real time, but also renders a comamnd field that the user types characters into.

I am just looking for an automated way to specify the properties of a command without creating a higher-level system to incur runtime bloat.